# Copy dataframe to existing excel file (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to copy a dataframe to the first empty rows of an existing excel file.

I already know how to copy the dataframe to a new file, but my intention is to keep on adding information to the same file, each time on the first empty rows available.

I've tried something like this, but it hasn't worked (I'm still getting used to working with Pandas):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

The excel's path I'm working with is the folder of my IDE (Spyder).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read in the existing dataframe

```
    df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
```

add any rows to this dataframe and then output it all, overwriting what was previously stored

```
    df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

From the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) this will always overwrite the previous sheet avoiding the chance of duplicating data.